# What are possible alternatives for "housing" in this context?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

In the following sentence:

> Yosemite National Park recently posted video of this bear climbing a tree near ranger **housing**.

I understand that *housing* here is a collective for quarters serving as accommodation to rangers during their shifts.

Would it saying "... climbing a tree near ranger **houses**" mean the same thing? Or would it carry any additional meaning (for instance would it imply they are the primary and permanent residence of the rangers, where they live with their families maybe, instead of being just their workplace?).

Or maybe are there any requirements for one to call them *houses*? For instance, if they lack a kitchen or living room found in common houses where people live then they can't be considered *houses*?

Another question: would "ranger dwellings" fit in this sentence as well?

Thanks!

Comment: Housing is not necessarily **houses**, it could be apartments or even tents. "Ranger housing" is a noun phrase, like "chicken soup". The important thing about the cited sentence, is that a bear was seen near to where rangers live. It's not about *how* rangers live, such as if they have a shared bathroom or kitchen (although that might be of interest to the bear).

Comment: One problem is that we don't know what you mean by "housing".

Comment: @WeatherVane So *ranger housing* has a broader meaning than *ranger houses* (because the latter physically describes the housing)? And regarding to *dwellings*, is it a perfect synonym to *housing* in this case?

Comment: The term "dwelling" is more usually used by architects, planners, lawyers etc.

Answer (score 1):

This usage of the word **housing** refers exactly as you said in the question; the place where the rangers are domiciled while working as a ranger.  The do not own the propertie(s) instead they use them in the previously mentioned capacity.  If you changed the word to **houses** would imply that these houses are owned by the rangers, while ranger **housing** would imply the buildings are owned by a third party (the government or company that manages the area).

To answer the second question, ranger dwellings could fit as well, but the distinction may or may not apply.

Comment: Thanks! Could you give an example of when the distinction would not apply?

Comment: What I mean is that dwelling can be used to mean somewhere a person lives, this may be their house, apartment, tent, etc... Which means that the distinction doesn't exist for dwelling where it does for housing and house.   So, the distinction may or may not apply, because dwelling can refer to either or house or housing.